# Finding and combining lines (Strings) together

Tags: java

So I have a String/txt file:
`All purchases: blabla : 1 derp : 20 blabla : 1 herp : 30`

This is just an example, a real file will be generated based on the users input

So what I need to do is combine the similar strings with similar names (First part) together and make them look like this: `(name) : (number) x(amount of same strings)`

For example lets take the file that we had:
`All purchases: blabla : 1 derp : 20 blabla : 1 herp : 30`

After parsing it must look like: `All purchases: blabla : 1 x2 derp : 20 herp : 30`

I have tried writing down the last value into a variable and checking it with the next value, but what if the values are in a different order? That's where I got stuck.

Comment: What if the numbers are different, like - `blabla : 1 derp : 20 blabla : 3`?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow. To prevent your question from being closed, explain [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you are stuck.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com? and see [ask]?

Comment: The numbers can't be different, thats a different item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each entry has three components:

[name] : [number] 
You can do a few things here. Something along the lines of:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("YourFileHere.txt"));
ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
while(s.hasNext())
{
    entries.add(s.next() + " " + s.next() + " " s.next());
}
```

You'll of course have to remove the leading 'All purchases:', but now everything is in the arraylist in the form [name] : [number] 

You simply have to determine how many of each there are. From here you can sort them and then count them.

Comment: No problem. Though do try to give a "Here's what I've tried". I answered simply because I figured you didn't know what to try.